# grails domain class .list() method with params

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have two domains that are connected with one-to-many relation - One User may have many Associations. I want to view all associations that belong to this user. I'm using scaffolding plugin. So code that should return list of Associations in AssociationController looks lile this:

```
def index(Integer max) {
    respond Association.list(params), model:[associationInstanceCount: Association.count()]
}
```

And on the User view page I have the following code:

```
<g:form controller="Association" >
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <g:hiddenField name="user.id" id="user.id" value="${userInstance.id}"/>
        <g:actionSubmit class="list" action="index" value="${message(code: 'default.list.label', default: 'Show Associations')}"/>
    </fieldset>
</g:form>
```

When I press this actionSubmit `user.id` is sent with the request and it is within params map (I checked it with debug) but for some reason `Association.list(params)` returns all Associations (for all users) despite the fact that I'm using this user.id within params. A also tried rename `user.id` to just `user` and it didn't work either. Seems like this .list() should be used only for sorting or I'm doing something wrong. Can you help me with this please? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To clarify the given answer: `list( params )` returns ALL results for the domain object, and accepts only sorting (order by) and view-port (limit/offset) parameters. It does not provide any `where` clause (well, apart from `discriminator`-column)

UPDATE:

you can use `findAllBy*`:

```
Association.findAllByUserId( params.long( 'user.id' ), params )
```

or `criteria` if you need to make your query more complex:

```
Association.withCriteria{
   eq 'id', params.long( 'user.id' )
   maxResults params.int( 'max' ) ?: 10
   firstResult params.int( 'offset' ) ?: 0
   if( params.sort && params.order ) order params.sort, params.order
}
```

Comment: Then I have one more question if you don't mind. How to combine this where {} with .list(params) in order to sort all entities that I want. For instance, I want to get all Associations that belong to particular user and sort them in some way because I want to use table with sorting. Previously when I used just Association.list(params) sorting worked. After I extended my code to Association.where { 
  user {
    eq 'id', params['user.id']
  }
} .list(params)
sorting broke. Association domain has widget and widget has name. But now when I sort it says could not resolve property: widget.name

Answer (score 4):

According to [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.6/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html), list does not take an id as parameter.

Seeing your max, it would be `Association.list(max: max)` and for what you want, it is something like:

```
Association.findAllByUserId(params.id, [max: max])
```

Where `params.id` contains the `id` of the wanted user (or `params['user.id']`).

More on [findAllBy...](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.6/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the previous response but :

```
Association.where { 
  user {
    eq 'id', params['user.id']
  }
} .list()
```

You can add params to list call if you use pagination.

Another solution :

```
def index(User user) {
  respond user.associations, , model:[associationInstanceCount: user.associations.size()]
}
```

But you'll have to name your param 'id'
It mostly depends on how you have designed your domain objects and what's your goal here.

Comment: and what if I want to sort all this Associations that belong to the particular user, would Association.where { 
  user {
    eq 'id', params['user.id']
  }
} .list(params) work?

Comment: That what the 'where' part is for.

Comment: Seems like but actually it doesn't work. Before that I used table with sorting and it worked and with this where it doesn't. For instance, Association has widget property and widget has name. I'm trying to sort by widget.name and now it says that Association doesn't have this property (previously it worked)

Comment: I can't help you much up to that point. I don't use where, and I favor HQL when I need to sort (or I use a finder queries). And my comment is out of the place, since I misread the "I want to sort".