# How to sort in grails list?

Tags: sorting, grails

I just started with grails and would like to sort a list by descending date. I tried this:

```
  <g:sortableColumn property="eventStartDate" defaultOrder="asc" title="${message(code: 'event.eventStartDate.label', default: 'Event Start Date')}" />
```

However this does not sort the list. The controller looks like this:

```
def list = {
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
    [eventInstanceList: Event.list(params), eventInstanceTotal: Event.count()]
}
```

How can I sort by descending eventStartDate?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Can you please make sure if you are sending these parameters: sort=eventStartDate&order=desc ?  Other than that, list(params) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it might not have worked is:

1. Event.list(params) retrieves everything.
2. You are sorting it in ascending order (asc) but you said you want to sort it in descending order (desc).

**Solution:**
Change the second line of your controller action to:

```
[eventInstanceList: Event.list(order: "desc"), eventInstanceTotal: Event.count()]
```

More info:
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html

`Event.list(params)` returns every thing in the domain object. It doesn't do any filtering. Use `findAllBy*` or `findBy*` or `createCriteria` instead.

Example:

```
Event.findAllByNameAndDate(params.get("name"), params.get("date"), [max: 10, order: "desc"])
```

More info:
[grails domain class .list() method with params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425887/grails-domain-class-list-method-with-params)